# Dynamically creating dataframes in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, dynamic-programming

I have few columns data coming out of a Dataframe 1, in a loop (from different rows). I want to create a Dataframe 2 with all this different rows/columns data.

Below is sample data, I tried using Seq:

```
var DF1 = Seq(
  ("11111111", "0101","6573","X1234",12763),
  ("44444444", "0148","8382","Y5678",-2883),
  ("55555555", "0154","5240","Z9011", 8003))
```

I want to add 2 dynamic rows below to the above Seq and then use the final Seq to create a Dataframe.

```
  ("88888888", "1333","7020","DEF34",500)
  ("99999999", "1333","7020","GHI56",500)
```

Final Seq or Dataframe should look like below:

```
   var DF3 = Seq(
      ("11111111", "0101","6573","X1234",12763),
      ("44444444", "0148","8382","Y5678",-2883),
      ("55555555", "0154","5240","Z9011", 8003),
      ("88888888", "1333","7020","DEF34",500),
      ("99999999", "1333","7020","GHI56",500))
```

Tried below code using Seq, created Case Class, to use it possibly. Problem is the when a new row is added to a Seq, it returns a new Seq with new row added in. How to get an updated Seq with new row added to it ? If not Seq, is ArrayBuffer a good idea to use ?

```
  case class CreateDFTestCaseClass(ACCOUNT_NO: String, LONG_IND: String, SHORT_IND: String,SECURITY_ID: String, QUANTITY: Integer)
  val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("AllocationOneViewTest")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()
  val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
  import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var acctRulesPosDF = Seq(
      ("11111111", "0101","6573","X1234",12763),
      ("44444444", "0148","8382","Y5678",-2883),
      ("55555555", "0154","5240","Z9011", 8003))
    acctRulesPosDF:+ ("88888888", "1333","7020","DEF34",500)
    acctRulesPosDF:+ ("99999999", "1333","7020","GHI56",500))
    var DF3 = acctRulesPosDF.toDF
    DF3.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant way, but keeping your code as similar to the original as possible, you just need to assign the result back to your variable.

```
 var acctRulesPosDF = Seq(
      ("11111111", "0101","6573","X1234",12763),
      ("44444444", "0148","8382","Y5678",-2883),
      ("55555555", "0154","5240","Z9011", 8003))
    acctRulesPosDF = acctRulesPosDF:+ ("88888888", "1333","7020","DEF34",500)
    acctRulesPosDF = acctRulesPosDF:+ ("99999999", "1333","7020","GHI56",500)
```

Quick example in the spark-shell

```
scala>  var acctRulesPosDF = Seq(
     |       ("11111111", "0101","6573","X1234",12763),
     |       ("44444444", "0148","8382","Y5678",-2883),
     |       ("55555555", "0154","5240","Z9011", 8003))
acctRulesPosDF: Seq[(String, String, String, String, Int)] = List((11111111,0101,6573,X1234,12763), (44444444,0148,8382,Y5678,-2883), (55555555,0154,5240,Z9011,8003))

scala>     acctRulesPosDF = acctRulesPosDF:+ ("88888888", "1333","7020","DEF34",500)
acctRulesPosDF: Seq[(String, String, String, String, Int)] = List((11111111,0101,6573,X1234,12763), (44444444,0148,8382,Y5678,-2883), (55555555,0154,5240,Z9011,8003), (88888888,1333,7020,DEF34,500))

scala>     acctRulesPosDF = acctRulesPosDF:+ ("99999999", "1333","7020","GHI56",500)
acctRulesPosDF: Seq[(String, String, String, String, Int)] = List((11111111,0101,6573,X1234,12763), (44444444,0148,8382,Y5678,-2883), (55555555,0154,5240,Z9011,8003), (88888888,1333,7020,DEF34,500), (99999999,1333,7020,GHI56,500))

scala> var DF3 = acctRulesPosDF.toDF
DF3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: string ... 3 more fields]

scala>     DF3.show()
+--------+----+----+-----+-----+
|      _1|  _2|  _3|   _4|   _5|
+--------+----+----+-----+-----+
|11111111|0101|6573|X1234|12763|
|44444444|0148|8382|Y5678|-2883|
|55555555|0154|5240|Z9011| 8003|
|88888888|1333|7020|DEF34|  500|
|99999999|1333|7020|GHI56|  500|
+--------+----+----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are get the same old Seq even you appended new rows is that, the Seq that is by default imported is of type `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`(which will not be changed) unless you specify separately to import mutable Seq `enter code here`using `scala.collection.mutable.Seq`. So either use mutable Seq by setting import explicitly in scala or do as suggested by @SCouto in the other answer.